# IntentService and CursorLoader Sychronisation issue

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contentprovider, android-cursorloader

I am building an app that follows the [IOSched](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/) way of retrieving data, with the exception of the fact that I thought I would use `CursorLoader` rather than `ContentObserver`:

I have also been referring to Reto's [android-protips-location](http://code.google.com/p/android-protips-location/) which does use `CursorLoader` and the logic flow is quite similar to IOSched, thus:

`initLoader → startService (serviceIntent) → handleIntent → insert into DB → notifyChange → onLoadFinished → update UI`

What I am expecting to see happen is `CursorLoader` return a `Cursor` once an `insert` has been performed on the database.

Currently, the fragment `onActivityCreated` calls `initLoader` and runs query on the `ContentProvider` this returns the `Cursor` for that point in time, with current data. 
However, it appears that `onLoadFinished` is not being triggered when I perform a refresh. Logs show that `delete` and `insert` on the `ContentProvider` are performed, yet viewing the log shows that `notifyChange` is dispatched on insert.

```
// in my Fragment:

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    refreshWelcome();
}

public void refreshWelcome() {
    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), SyncService.class);
    i.setAction(SyncService.GET_WELCOME);
    getActivity().startService(i);
}

public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    Uri queryUri = AppContract.Welcome.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = new String[] { Welcome.WELCOME_FIRST_NAME };
    String where = null;
    String[] whereArgs = null;
    String sortOrder = null;
    // create new cursor loader
    CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(), queryUri, projection, where, whereArgs, sortOrder);
    return loader;
}


//in AppProvider (which extends ContentProvider)

@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
    final SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    final int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
    switch (match) {
    case WELCOME: {
          long rowId = db.insertOrThrow(Tables.WELCOME, null, values);
          if (rowId > 0) {
             getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
             return uri;
          }
       }
    }
   return null;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason for using a CursorLoader in an IntentService?  The IntentService is a queue that performs work in a separate thread.  Why not directly perform the query?

Answer (score 0):

As far I know, you receive the cursor in onLoadFinished; onCreateLoader returns a Loader< Cursor>.

I do it this way, setting the notification Uri for the cursor just after received it. It works fine for me.

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor>loader, Cursor data) {
    Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "onLoadFinished");
    data.setNotificationUri(getActivity().getContentResolver(),yourURI);
    ((SimpleCursorAdapter) getListAdapter()).swapCursor(data);
    if (data.getCount() == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "no elements",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
    }
<}
```